# A question regarding non-(Lebesgue)-measurable sets in models of ZFC+$2^{\aleph_0}$=$\aleph_2$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $\mathscr V$ represent a set of Vitali's type. It is known that $|\mathscr V|=2^{\aleph_0}$.  Does $\mathscr V$ have any measure-theoretic properties in models of, say, $\mathrm{ZFC}+2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ that differ from its measure-theoretic properties in ZFC+CH?

Comment: As you can see, I have corrected the problem. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds a little too broad to me. Do you have something more specific in mind?

Comment: @tomasz:  Actually, the motivation for this question is Freiling's Axiom of Symmetry, that is, the axiom that states (at least according to the formulation of it given by Wikipedia) that, if A represents the set of functions mapping real numbers in the unit interval [0,1] to countable sets of of the same interval, then for every f in A, there exist x and y such that x$\notin$f(y) and y$\notin$f(x).  Sierpinski shows that a varition of this which is equivalant to this is also logically equivalent to $\lnot$CH.  Freiling uses the following thought experiment involving throwing darts at the

Comment: (cont.) interval [0,1] (also from Wikipedia):  "Fix a function in A.  We will consider a thought experiment that involves throwing darts at [0,1].  We aren't able to physically determine with infinite accuracy that the actual values of the numbers x and y that are hit.  Likewise, the question of whether 'y$\in$f(x)' cannot actually be physically computed.  Nevertheless, if f really is a function, then this question is a meaningful one and will have a definite 'yes' or 'no' answer.  Now wait until after the first dart, x, is thrown and then assess the chances that the second dart y will be

Comment: (cont.) in f(x).  Since x is now fixed, f(x) is a fixed countable set and has Lebesgue measure zero.  Therefore this event, with x fixed has probability zero.  Freiling now makes two generalizations:  i) Since we can predict with virtual certainty that 'y$\notin$f(x)' after the first dart is thrown,and since this prediction is valid no matter what the first dart does, we should be able to make this prediction before the first dart is thrown.  This is not to say that we still have a measurable event, rather it is an intuition about the nature of being predictable; ii) Since 'y$\notin$f(x)'

Comment: (cont.) is predictably true, by the symmetry of the order in which the darts were thrown (hence the name 'Axiom of Symmetry') we should also be able to predict with actual certainty that 'x$\notin$f(y).  The Axiom of Symmetry is now justified based on the principle that what will predictably happen every time this experiment is performed, should at least be possible.  hence there should exist two real numbers x and y such that x$\notin$f(y) and y$\notin$f(x)."  Note that one can replace [0,1] with $\mathscr V$ since both have the same cardinality, and A can be defined as the set of all

Comment: (cont.) functions mapping elements of $\mathscr V$ to countable subsets of $\mathscr V$.  Note also that regardless of whether or not the countable subsets of $\mathscr V$ are Lebesgue measurable or not, because of the model of ZFC chosen (i.e. where |$\mathscr V$|=$\aleph_2$) because $\aleph_0$$\lt$$\aleph_2$, there will exist x and y such that x$\notin$f(y) and y$\notin$f(x).  Likewise, in models where |$\mathscr V$|=$\aleph_1$ (i.e. where CH holds) the very opposite will happen, so Freiling's justification of the Axiom of Symmetry is valid regardless of whether $\mathscr V$ and its

Comment: (cont.) countable subsets are Lebesgue measurable or not.  Thus I ask the question to check if my intuition is valid or not.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Two comments: There is no such thing as "the" Vitali set. A Vitali set is a set of reals that contains one member from each equivalence class under the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$. In ZF + DC, every Vitali set has zero inner measure and positive outer measure. If this does not answer your (non existent) question try formulating it again.

Comment: Have edited the question. Are you saying that a set of Vitali's type does not have different measure-theoretic properties under $\lnot$CH than under CH? What proof can you offer me that the aforementioned sentence is true? Also, it is well known that under full AC a set of Vitali's type is not Lebesgue measurable.  What type of measures are the inner and outer measure you refer to, and please provide a reference if not a link to the relevant cites.

Comment: @Thomas: [Outer measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) and [inner measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_measure) are rather basic concepts in measure theory. It’s easily proved that if the Lebesgue outer measure of a set is $0$, the set is Lebesgue measurable, so the outer measure of a Vitali set must be positive. If its inner measure were positive, it would contain a Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure, and the usual proof that a Vitali set is non-measurable shows that this is impossible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Regarding my question, do you believe it to be a 'non-question' and if so, can you prove this assertion?  Also, regarding your comment to me, does a set of Vitali's type have zero inner measure and positive outer measure under full AC as well (I ask because of your comment "the usual proof that a Vitali set is non-measurable shows that this [a Vitali set having a positive inner measure] is impossible)"?

Comment: @Thomas: Solovay has a model of $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ in which Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ is total, and there are no Vitali sets; thus, you need more choice than $\mathsf{DC}$ just to ensure that there even is a Vitali set. The statement about inner and outer measure is true whenever you have a Vitali set. As for you question, *measure-theoretic properties* is a bit vague/broad.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  What is the minimal choice axiom needed to ensure that sets of Vitali's type exist?

Comment: (cont.) or (possibly better put...) if ZF+DC+"$\aleph_1$$\le$|$\mathbb R$|" can prove that there exists an unmeasurable set, is that set a set of Vitali's type, and if so, are these the weakest assumptions necessary to ensure that sets of Vitali's type exist?

Comment: @Thomas: Having a well-ordering of $\Bbb R$ is sufficient to get a Vitali set; I don’t know whether a weaker choice assumption suffices, or even whether it is known; I do know that weaker choice assumptions suffice to ensure the existence of non-measurable sets of reals. It is not true that $\mathsf{ZF+DC+\aleph_1\le|\Bbb R}|$ ensures the existence of a non-measurable set of reals: Solovay’s model is a counterexample.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for the information--it was certainly helpful.

Comment: @Thomas: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I have one more question. Assume you have constructed a Vitali set $\mathscr V$ over the interval [0,1].  Is the complement $\mathscr V^{/}$ of $\mathscr V$ measurable or nonmeasurable, or, does it depend on the choice of the Vitali set you construct?

Comment: @Thomas: It's non-measurable: the complement of a measurable set is measurable, so the complement of a non-measurable set is necessarily non-measurable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Thanks.  So with  Vitali set $\mathscr V$ and its complement $\mathscr V^{/}$ defined over the interval [0,1], one has, since $\mathscr V$$\cap$$\mathscr V^{/}$=$\emptyset$, $\mathscr V$$\cup$$\mathscr V^{/}$=[0,1], correct?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Brian M.Scott:  So now assume that $\mathscr V$ has been constructed and now color the points in $\mathscr V$ your favorite color--now $\mathscr V$ and $\mathscr V^{/}$ have been fixed on [0,1].  Now imagine throwing a dart at the interval [0,1] such that it is thrown 'randomly' enough that it hits somewhere in [0,1] but it is undetermined where.  By construction of $\mathscr V$ and by $\mathscr V$$\cup$$\mathscr V^{/}$=[0,1], the dart must hit either $\mathscr V$ or $\mathscr V^{/}$.  What can be said, if anything, regarding the probability that the dart will either hit $\mathscr V$

Comment: (cont.) or $\mathscr V^{/}$?

Comment: @Thomas: Nothing, in my opinion: you need a probability measure to make the question meaningful.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Is it possible to define a probability measure on Lebesgue non-measurable sets?  If so, it would seem to solve some possible misunderstandings regarding Freiling's "dart" example.